# Agreeing to only do "academic research", doing academic research, but then spinning off a startup based on academic research

Tags: contract-law

If I sign a material transfer agreement (MTA) to use a material only for "academic research", do legitimate academic research, but then spin off a startup based on that academic research, does this violate the terms of the MTA?

Specifically, I'm currently deciding whether to sign an MTA that states:

> You may use this Material (including the viral based vectors
>   referenced in #1 above) only for the specific research project
>   described in the MTA, which is: "academic research."

I intend to only use the material (viral vectors) for scientific research, but I don't want to be constrained in the future if I want to start a startup based on my research - this is the end goal of my PhD. My instincts tell me that these agreements fully handle and allow that case, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: I think this is a question you need to ask of a lawyer (whom, yes, you will have to pay), instead of random people on the Internet.

Comment: Or, tell the other party that you want language in the agreement making it clear, to your satisfaction (and ideally your lawyer's) that this is allowed.  Of course, if they didn't want to allow it, you have a problem, but better to know now than when they sue you.

Answer (score 2):

The MTA controls what you can do with the *material,* not with the research.

Given that your startup does not physically deal with any of the actual material transferred (or its progeny), it does not violate the MTA.